# Eclipse linked folder error "does not match the expected package"

Tags: android, eclipse

This is ADT v21.0.1-543035

I have Project1 in my Eclipse workspace.  I've added Project2 and am attempting to create a linked folder pointing to a util folder in Project1.  I added the linked folder as follows:

- In the Eclipse Project2, right-click on src and choose New... Folder.
- Click Advanced, select Linked Folder.
- Click Variables, choose WORKSPACE_LOC, click Extend, browse to the folder to be linked, e.g. Project1/src/com/mycompany/demo/util/
- Click OK.
- Back at the New Folder dialog, edit the Folder Name to be the full path, e.g. com.mycompany.demo.util
- Click Finish.

Eclipse adds the linked folder, but shows the following error in the console:

```
The declared package "com.mycompany.demo.util" does not match the expected package "com.mycompany.demo.util"
```

When I view the linked folder's properties, it shows the path as:

```
/Project1/src/com.mycompany.demo.util
```

Whereas the same linked folder in a different project looks like:

```
/Project1/src/com/mycompany/demo/util
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to my question "why" creating the linked folder didn't work, but here's how I fixed it.

I exited Eclipse and looked at Project2's *.project* file, I saw that it had the following:

```
<linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>src/com.mycompany.demo.util</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <locationURI>WORKSPACE_LOC/Project1/src/com/mycompany/demo/util</locationURI>
  </link>
</linkedResources>
```

I looked at the *name* token for another project where the linked folder was working, and it had the value:

```
    <name>src/com/mycompany/demo/util</name>
```

So I edited Project2's *name* to contain slashes, restarted Eclipse and cleaned Project2.

Project2 now showed two entries in the src folder:

- a linked folder named com.mycompany.demo.util, with a warning indicator icon
- a regular folder with the same name, also with a warning indicator icon

I deleted the regular folder entry and checked the linked folder's properties.  The Path looked fine, but the Location was not set.  I clicked Edit, set the value using the WORKSPACE_LOC variable as described in my original question, and voila!  Eclipse now resolves the linked folder correctly.